# Touchscreen is being recognized as a mouse

Tags: touchpad, qt, touchscreen, multi-touch, xinput

I plugged in a 3M touchscreen to my Linux PC. It appears as it recognizes it as a mouse. Here's my `xinput` output:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 3M 3M USB Touchscreen - 36955             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)
```

After `# modprobe -r usbtouchscreen` touching device stops working.

On Windows 7 it works after installing driver from [this site](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Electronics_NA/Electronics/Tools_Support/Support/) so I also tried to install Linux driver from here (Linux, Single Touch, 64bit). I think installation process fails as it interrupts immediately after I accept the license (with 0 exit code).

I test my touchscreen with [Qt FingerPaint example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-touch-fingerpaint-example.html) (also works on Windows, doesn't work on Ubuntu). Debugging shows that multitouch input generates mouse events.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.10.0-35-generic and tried both Unity and Cinnamon environments. I need this working for programming purposes.

**EDIT:**

Some diagnostic tools output:

```
# lsinput
...some other devices...
/dev/input/event12
bustype : BUS_USB
vendor  : 0x596
product : 0x1
version : 1088
name    : "3M 3M USB Touchscreen - 36955"
phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0"
bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS


# mtdev-test /dev/input/event12
015ee1f66c7c 00 1 014a 1
015ee1f66c7c 00 3 0000 12183
015ee1f66c7c 00 3 0001 7962
015ee1f66c7c 00 0 0000 0
015ee1f66c80 00 3 0000 12193
... etc ...
```

**EDIT:**

```
$ xinput list-props 12
Device '3M 3M USB Touchscreen - 36955':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (268): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (262):    1430, 1
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event12"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (272): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (273):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (274):  0
    Axis Labels (275):  "Abs X" (266), "Abs Y" (267)
    Button Labels (276):    "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Wheel Up" (149), "Button Wheel Down" (150)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (277): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (278):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (279):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (280): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (281): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (282):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (283):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (284):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (285):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (286):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (287):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (288): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (289):  0
```

And evtest:

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event12
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x596 product 0x1 version 0x440
Input device name: "3M 3M USB Touchscreen - 36955"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value   6684
      Min        0
      Max    16384
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   6185
      Min        0
      Max    16384
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1507280785.112401, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1507280785.112401, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 5971
Event: time 1507280785.112401, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 6240
Event: time 1507280785.112401, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1507280785.116364, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 5953
Event: time 1507280785.116364, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1507280785.118359, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 5968
Event: time 1507280785.118359, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
# ...........
Event: time 1507280785.156333, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1507280785.158356, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1507280785.158356, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: Please output `xinput list-props 12` command in your question.

Comment: Have checked the behaviour of your device with the tool [`evtest`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/evtest.1.html) (you should use `sudo evtest`)?

Comment: @pa4080 updated

Comment: Have you tried MultiTouch? Did you related 3M about this interruption after drver installation you told?

Comment: @Redbob MultiTouch is a kernel patch, I assume I have to recompile a kernel to install it as it is a script that modifies some source files. I don't want to do that, it's a lot of work. I didn't report a crash yet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install a new kernel to check wheter the new one has firmware for it.
First  of all verify which is the current kernel in your system by using the command

```
uname -a
```

You can manually install kernel 4.13 as its the current stable one.

1. Proceed to [ubuntu kernel 4.13](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/)
2. Based on your uname -a output make sure what your system/os arch is,If it was X86_64 then its a 64 bit,if it was X86 then its a 32 bits.
3. Make a folder somewhere in your system naming it 4.13, you can also use the command

   ```
   mkdir 4.13
   ```
4. Enter into the 4.13 directory, now select the files based on your arch

   - **64 bit list**:  If its 64 bits choose this ones  i.e X86_64:

     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_all.deb
     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_amd64.deb
     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-image-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_amd64.deb
   - **32 bit list**: If its 32 bits aka X86 then choose this:

     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_all.deb
     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-headers-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_i386.deb
     - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/linux-image-4.13.0-041300-generic_4.13.0-041300.201709031731_i386.deb

   You can save the either list in a text file for example "kernel_files.list".
   Now in terminal use wget to download this files.

   ```
   wget -i kernel_files.list
   ```

   This will download the entire list using wget.
5. Now proceed with installtion of them

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   This will install all the 3 kernel components together,at last you would see that all kernels have compiled.
6. Reboot your system to use the new kernel

   ```
   reboot
   ```
7. Verify the installation of new kernel by issuing the command

   ```
   uname -a
   ```

Now check whether the touch screen works properly or not.

Check whether the system is getting inputs through it using

```
dmesg
```

If it still fails, then install

```
make,gcc,g++,build-utils
```

by issuing the command

```
sudo apt install make gcc g++ build-utils
```

and then install the touch screen drivers again.

**Note #1**: If you are not confident to install the new kernel manually then you can use ukuu instead,

For installing ukuu

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Then run ukuu and install 4.13 kernel using ukuu dashboard.

**Note #2**: You can always switch back to your previous kernel by issuing C  during boot of your Ubuntu based machine.

**Note #3**: Keep your touchscreen and screen dust free and should not have moisture,oil,dirt,etc in it.

**Note #4**: use a touch pen as it would be more accurate than your finger.

**Note #5**: kernel 4.14 is under testing so don't install that

Comment: I know how to upgrade the kernel but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: if kernel or drivers dont fix the issue then cant say